# how to use zmq_msg_more correctly?

Tags: c, zeromq

Code Connected Volume 1 - page 47 have an example about how to receive multipart message:

```
while (1) {
    zmq_msg_t message;
    zmq_msg_init(&message);
    zmq_msg_recv(&message, socket, 0);
    // Process the message frame
    ...
    zmq_msg_close(&message);
    if (!zmq_msg_more(&message))
        break;
}
```

Is this correct? Shouldn't we use `zmq_msg_close()` after `zmq_msg_more()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API reference for [zmq_msg_more()](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-msg-more) and [zmq_msg_recv()](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-msg-recv) (ZeroMQ 3.2.2 Stable) both contain examples showing that [zmq_msg_close()](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-msg-close) is called **after** zmq_msg_more. As far as I know the API docs do not specifically state anything to contradict this, thus the example from Code Connected seems wrong. The documentation for `zmq_msg_close()` states that the actual memory release may be postponed by underlaying layers, implicating that the `zmq_msg_more()` operation *may* succeed but it still looks wrong to call it after closing the message.

Example from [zmq_msg_more() API documentation (3.2.2)](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-msg-more) (edited slightly for readability):

```
zmq_msg_t part;
while (true) 
{
    //  Create an empty ØMQ message to hold the message part
    int rc = zmq_msg_init (&part);
    assert (rc == 0);

    //  Block until a message is available to be received from socket
    rc = zmq_recvmsg (socket, &part, 0);
    assert (rc != -1);

    if (zmq_msg_more (&part))
        fprintf (stderr, "more\n");
    else 
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "end\n");
        break;
    }
    zmq_msg_close (part); 
}
```

However, looking in the ZeroMq Guide regarding [Multi-Part Messages](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Multi-part-Messages), that example actually checks for more messages **after** closing the message, but that is achieved by checking the socket using [zmq_getsockopt()](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-getsockopt), **without** using any references to the message. I suspect the Code Connected examples simply used that example and changed from `zmq_getsockopt()` to `zmq_msg_more()` (probably incorrecly so).

Example from [ZeroMq Guide (multi-part messages)](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Multi-part-Messages):

```
while (1) 
{
    zmq_msg_t message;
    zmq_msg_init (&message);
    zmq_msg_recv (&message, socket, 0);
    //  Process the message frame
    zmq_msg_close (&message);
    int more;
    size_t more_size = sizeof (more);
    zmq_getsockopt (socket, ZMQ_RCVMORE, &more, &more_size);
    if (!more)
        break;      //  Last message frame
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer will help someone.

from "libzmq/doc/zmq_msg_more.txt"

*The *zmq_msg_more()* function indicates whether this is part of a multi-part
message, and there are further parts to receive. This method **can safely be
called after *zmq_msg_close()***. This method is identical to *zmq_msg_get()*
with an argument of ZMQ_MORE.*